# JAX-RS (Jersey) Admin Only API Calls

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

This may turn out to be more of a style question, but I'm a little stumped on how best to design a RESTful API.

Let's say I want to provide the following API calls:

- GET /player

  - Returns the current player
- GET /player/{id}

  - Returns the specified player
- POST /admin/player/{id}

  - Registers the specified Player
- PUT /admin/player/{id}

  - Updates the specified Player

As you probably surmised, the last two require administrative rights, and the first two merely require a user to be logged into the system.

So my question involves how best to lay this API out into resources.  My first instinct is to create a single PlayerResource that doesn't have a class-level @Path annotation, but rather defines each method with `@Path("player/...")` or `@Path("admin/player/...")` accordingly.  Will that work?  It just smells a bit to me, so is there a better way to do this style-wise?  The only alternative I can think of is to create a separate resource class to contain the admin-only calls, but that smells to me too since I'd have two resources dealing with the same model class.

I'm just looking for a little guidance on how best to design this thing.  This is my first RESTful web app, so forgive my horrible ignorance.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not go with having a seperate resource for admin calls.
If the User making the call doesnt have the rights to POST or PUT to the specific resource, do return a 401-Unauthorized Status Code. That's, in my opinion, the only proper and intended way of doing it.

EDIT after Comment:

As you mentioned, you have your security constraints defined via web.xml, I guess you will have User Roles.

This will allow you the following :)

```
@PUT
@RolesAllowed("ADMIN")
public void register(User user){......)
```

You just have to put the https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/1.5/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/container/filter/RolesAllowedResourceFilterFactory.html in place :)

EDIT2

My Resources always look like this. (Exceptions allowed :) )

```
@Path("/players")
public class PlayerResource{
  @GET
  public List<Player> list(){}

  @GET
  @Path("{id}")
  public Player get(@PathParam("id")Long id){}

  @DELETE
  @RolesAllowed("ADMIN")
  @Path("{id}")
  public Player delete(@PathParam("id")Long id){}

  //PUT and POST ommited

}
```

regards

Comment: Well, I realized one thing I didn't mention.  I'm attempting to secure  everything in the admin/* path using a security constraint in web.xml.  Is this option still viable?  To state it another way, I'm not actually checking any authorization stuff in these methods.  I'm depending upon Google App Engine for that, I guess.  Maybe that's where I'm making a rookie mistake, but it seemed to be the way GAE lead me.

Comment: check the edit, it should be possible via Annotations. So you dont need to have complicated code going on in every method, you want to have restricted access to.

Comment: So, in general, it's okay to not define a top-level path on the class and repeat, in this example, @Path("/player/...") several times?  I guess this is my style question.  Thanks so much for the prompt response.  Really helps me learn!

Comment: If non-admins never PUT or POST, and those are the only admin operations, use HTTP method constraints as your hook points.

Comment: You realy should read this one https://blog.apigee.com/detail/restful_api_design
It helped me gaining much insight and is my "way to rest"

Comment: Ohhhhhhh! It just clicked.  Sorry for being a little dense!  I need to simply remove the /admin path.  Duh!  Thanks so much for all the help!

Comment: Interestingly enough, I don't think Google App Engine permits the use of the @RolesAllowed annotation.  Too bad.  Looks like I might have to go a more manual route of checking authorization in each REST call.  Seems to me there ought to be a better way, but I've yet to find it.

Comment: Humm, you might implement Annotation-based role checking by yourself. Just study the source of https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.5/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/container/filter/RolesAllowedResourceFilterFactory.html and try to adapt it to your needs. I have done custom annotation by myself and it works

Comment: @kfis The problem is that, as it turns out, the thing that's really missing from GAE is the set of classes in J2EE's javax.annotation.security.  The issue is noted in the [GAE Google Code page](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=annotations&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log&groupby=&sort=&id=2320)

Comment: wow, now this is weak...since 2009...interesting...Still you might roll with your own custom annotations